Plotly express graphs are not showing on GitHub repo jupyter notebook
I've created ipynb project notebook on my machine, and it was working normally.
after uploading it to GitHub, plotly graphs are not showing there anymore.
Ant solution on how to show them up?
https://github.com/MoHassan01/Airbnb/blob/main/main.ipynb

Does this answer your question? How to display plotly graph in github (from jupyter notebook)?

That in theory should answer your question. However, your supplied example is nowhere near a minimal reproducible example. Read How do I ask a good question?, especially the section under 'Help Other Reproduce Your Problem'. Then make a simple notebook with one plot and share that in your post instead of this one. I'm wondering if your notebook is just too large and taxing the resources of nbviewer. I'll try to look later. I see some data in that file for the plots when I look at your .ipynb file as text. I don't know though if it got encoded ....

 correctly or it is just the size causing an issue at this point.

I have edited the post to have the notebook link directly, and i will try making another sample notebook, sorry for the inconvenience

I'm still trying to solve the main problem btw, i've seen the question you've linked before, but i'm still facing problems in implementing it to my code

So far an adapted (changed the data file name) of your main3.ipynb file where I stripped out everything but the first plot works well rendered in nbviewer. By contrast, the source on GitHub though fails to show the plot because it is simply a preview meant for developers and has more limited abilities. To make that, I cloned your repo into sessions launched from here and ran until that point.

 And here it is working on the Jupyter Community provided-tool for sharing static notebooks, nbviewer, with two plots: here. Again, note that Github's preview doesn't show the plots as expected at this time.

Actually i tried to open the main notebook via nbviewer, and the plots either do not show or take too long to render
https://nbviewer.org/github/MoHassan01/Airbnb/blob/main/main.ipynb

Yes, but that is a different problem than you posted about. Read your title carefully. It currently is "Plotly express graphs are not showing on GitHub repo jupyter notebook". And this is true they aren't expected to show up and you should be using nbviewer. Making a minimal reproducible example from the start of your notebook, I have shown that one could reasonably expect Plotly express plots to show up in nbviewer. So that is the solution to the title you have posted about. And it is a duplicate of what I linked to. Your issue may be a different one. I'm still trying to determine.

So it is something about how you are doing this or a version difference in the environment where you are working vs mine. I cloned your repo and ran your main.ipynb file. (In my comment above I detailed where I ran this.) Then I saved that and uploaded it to gist. First the fist upload timed out. Second attempt it worked okay and importantly nbviewer renders it just fine here!. The source of the ipynb file at GitHub that is rendering is here.

 Either way it is a problem that isn't reproducible and so the solution won't probably help that many others. Unless I'm mistaken. Most notably as the title stands it wont help others. The StackOverflow post I pointed to already covers this and the solution is to put the GitHub URL in nbviewer and then you'll see the plots. If we can track down the actual cause here of the difference then you could create a different post with a more specific title about your issue. However, as it stands, this current title and post itself is solved.

Minor thing to put on your radar for down the road. The line df = df[~df.groupby('neighbourhood')['price'].apply(is_outlier)] in your main.ipynb fails with Pandas 2.0.2 & Python 3.10. While it works fine with Pandas 1.3.5 & Python 3.7.

Thanks so much, let me check it and try getting it to work by myself.

TL;DR:
You should be able to take the GitHub URL and put it in the form at nbviewer and it should render the Plotly plots in the 'static' view of the notebook.
Details
(I put 'static' in quotes because using the right tool, you can get javascript backed things to work and still be interactive in nbviewer.)
nbviewer is the Jupyter Community provided solution for sharing Jupyter Notebooks with non-developers. It has many features not present in the preview that GitHub provides for developers. Rendering Plotly plots is one of several. It used the be more common that newcomers to the Jupyter ecosystem would learn this faster because GitHub wouldn't even attempt to make a preview if the Jupyter .ipynb file was over 100 kb and suggested nbviewer. Sadly, the change to attempting a rudimentary preview for developers has resulted in newcomers not realizing the tool they seek is nbviewer and they they simple need to direct nbviewer at the GitHub resource. (Actually, nbviewer can work with most any publically available static link.)
Specifics about how the OP's saved .ipynb file not rendering at nbviewer at this time is non-reproducible
So it is something about how you are doing this or a version difference in the environment where you are working vs. mine that seems to be contributing to your saved .ipynb file failing to display the plots in the nbviewer render.
I cloned your repo and ran your main.ipynb file. (Below details how and where I ran this further.) Then I saved that and uploaded it to GitHub's gist site. Importantly, nbviewer renders it just fine here!.
The source of the .ipynb file at GitHub that is rendering is here.
Presumably investigating the code in the saved .ipynb source file vs. mine should reveal a difference that may give insight to what is going on. However, the only example provided by the OP to date has a lot of plots and makes comparison difficult. I have stressed that a minimal reproducible example would be better and this would make comparison of the text code in the saved .ipynb files much more straightforward. All my saves work and so I cannot make the failing example myself.
Details on how and where I ran the OP's code
I cloned your repo into MyBinder-served Jupyter sessions launched from here. (One can just go there and click the 'launch binder' badge to get a session in your browser without logging in. The environment in that image aleady has all the necessary packages and so nothing needs to be installed.) Then I ran the entire main.ipynb to make sure it worked. I saved that fresh-rerun of the notebook to my system and then uploaded it to GitHub as a gisthere.  (Although the first upload attempt timed out, presumably due to the size of the notebook,  the second upload attempt it worked okay.) Then I put that URL in the form at nbviewer.
The nbviewer rendering of the entire main.ipynb run fresh in my environment looks good.
